# Create a bootable USB of Windows PE on linux

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, iso-image

How can I create a bootable USB using Windows PE ISO on linux?

Note - Any Windows PE ISO available on web which supports creating a bootable  USB from linux will be helpful (please mention the steps or reference as well).

Background -
I have Hiren’s BootCD PE and wanted to create a bootable USB from Linux. Followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146127/how-do-i-create-a-bootable-usb-on-ubuntu-from-hirens-boot-cd-iso-for-windows) but the problem is that  all answers refer to a HBCD folder which doesn't exist anymore in the ISO.(A weird thing I noted that even menu.lst file refers to the HBCD folder)

Other guides need Windows to create the bootable USB but currently I have access to Linux only (and trying to troubleshoot windows which isn't booting)

Directly booting from USB created using unetbootin doesn't help.

I don't like running wine so answers without using them will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Hiren's BootCD PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) contains both BIOS and UEFI loaders.  You can therefore simply copy the contents of the ISO onto a suitably formatted USB key.  The same procedure will work with other pre-built PE (such as [Kyhi](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/27180-windows-10-recovery-tools-bootable-rescue-disk.html?s=061efa91b8e06311d19ff236359a3eb0) or [Gandalf](https://win10rescue.com/index.php?p=/discussion/14/gandalf-s-windows-10-pe-x64-28-7-2019)) or a Windows ISO as long as the `.wim`is less than 4GB.

**Format USB**

If you want a USB that can boot on either BIOS/CSM or UEFI you need to format it with a MBR partition table containing a FAT32 partition marked active.

1. BIOS/CSM will only boot Windows from MBR partitioned drives while UEFI will boot from either MBR or GPT so you want MBR partition scheme.
2. BIOS/CSM will boot from either FAT or NTFS.  UEFI *may* boot from NTFS (if there is a UEFI driver in firmware) but will definitely boot from FAT.  The largest file on the Hiren's  *Boot.wim* is 1.32GB and as this is less than 4GB there is not reason not to use FAT32.  If you had larger files you could make separate FAT and NTFS partitions and include a UEFI NTFS driver but this is not required.
3. BIOS/CSM will only boot if partition is marked active, UEFI doesn't care so mark it active.

Assuming your USB key is `sdc` (check with lsblk) you can do this as follows:

- Create partition table and partition using [fdisk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fdisk).  Enter  `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc` and then following options:
- `o` to create a new empty DOS partition table
- `n` , `p`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>,  <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `y` to create new primary partition accepting defaults and deleting any filesystem signature.
- `t`, `b` to change partition type to FAT32
- `a` to set partition bootable.
- `w` to write changes.
- Disconnect and reconnect USB to pick up partition.
- Format partition using [mkfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFI_system_partition#Format_the_partition) : `sudo mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdc1`

**Copy data**

- Mount ISO (assuming Hiren's in *Downloads* directory).
- `sudo mkdir /mnt/dvd/`
- `sudo mount -o loop ~/Downloads/HBCD_PE_x64.iso /mnt/dvd`
- Copy everything from ISO to USB (assuming USB mounted at /run/media/*user*/*Volume*)
- `sudo cp -R /mnt/dvd/* /run/media/<user>/<Volume>`

Comment: Have a look at this answer and the comment - need to install Grub4DOS as they aren't hybrid ISO : https://askubuntu.com/a/146128

Comment: The [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/146128) is 8 years old.  If you follow the link in the comment to [Hiren's](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/usb-booting/)  it doesn't mention Grub4DOS - it says *"Hiren’s BootCD PE supports UEFI booting from DVD and USB flash drives. To format, re-partition your USB drive and to copy the ISO content into your USB drive properly, we have developed Hiren’s BootCD PE"* .  In any case this answer is not using `dd` but mounting ISO and then copying contents.  I tested on a Arch Linux machine and the resulting USB booted fine (in UEFI mode on a MacBook).

Comment: Under `fdisk` I have to hit `a`, not `b` to toggle bootable flag!

Comment: @F.Hauri - corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using Woeusb I was able to create the bootable USB for Windows PE.

Comment: As you know,  the question asks for detailed steps and references.

Comment: A really simple and universal solution that does not require additional details.