# Cannot install Windows 10 from USB stick - issue with GRUB?

Tags: windows, installation, grub, bootloader, usb-storage

I have followed the instructions [here](https://wycd.net/posts/2015-03-10-creating-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-drive-on-linux.html) and created a bootable Windows 10 USB stick, but when I try to run the installation the system keeps booting into the GRUB 2.0 bootloader. Unfortunately, I have no experience with GRUB.

The current system is set up for dual-booting Windows 10 and Linux Mint Debian Edition 4 - I recall the setup process being extremely long and involved (for my level of experience) and for some reason I cannot boot into Windows at all: After selecting it in the GRUB menu, the screen turns black for a moment and then immediately returns to the menu.

How do I make the system boot from the USB stick, so I can throw everything from the disk and make a fresh Windows 10 installation?

UPDATE 1: Out of desperation, I booted into a Linux on another USB stick and used `dd` to overwrite the first few megabytes of the hard drive with zeros. Upon restart, however, I get this error:

```
Cannot boot from any device

  Current boot order and device status
   1: USB HDD:   Model XYZ (USB) -> No valid operating system
   2: ATAPI CD0: Model XYZ (DVD) -> No valid operating system
   3: ATA HDD0:  Model XYZ (HDD) -> No valid operating system
```

Is it the ISO on the USB stick after all? If yes, can anyone recommend a good tool for Linux to create a proper bootable Windows 10 USB stick? Unfortunately, I cannot install `WoeUSB` as suggested below.

UPDATE 2: I used `disks` to have a look at the USB stick and noticed that the option "Bootable" was not activated. I checked the box and now the system seems to boot into the Windows setup, but the process gets interrupted with the following error code:

> Recovery
>
> Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Error code: 0xc00002c4
>
> You'll need to use recovery tools. If you don't have any installation media (like a disc or USB device), contact your PC administrator or PC/Device manufacturer.
>
> Press Enter to try again
>
> Press F8 for Startup Settings

Pressing Enter or F8 just returns me to the error screen. I couldn't find any helpful information on this, does anybody know about this error code?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: You need to change boot order : https://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/amp/

Comment: @Madhubala: Thanks, boot order is already...in order. The USB drive is on position 1

Comment: Create a bootable Win PE USB then use WinNT setup to install Windows or  create another bootable USB

Comment: Create bootable Win PE on Linux:https://superuser.com/a/1518254

Answer (score 0):

Most websites are now using WoeUSB to create a Window 10 USB

https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/

If you can get on to a Windows machine you can create USB from Microsoft directly. I've do it this way at least half a dozen times last year.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10ISO

Also the way to download the latest version of Windows ISO

Comment: Thanks, I will try WoeUSB. However, I'm not sure if the bootable USB stick is the issue here, I followed the instructions in the tutorial I linked and GRUB seems to correctly recognize the Windows 10 ISO files on it. I rather suspect this to be an issue with GRUB as it won't transition to the Windows setup, but immediately jumps back to the menu

Comment: Ok, I tried to follow the installation steps for WoeUSB, but there seems to some problems with the package and dependencies...I would post the terminal output, but I don't think this will really solve the issue (= forcing the system to boot into the Windows 10 setup)